# How to get the XPath for an element?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am trying to programmatically get the XPath of an element of a webpage.

I am searching the HTML source for a specific pattern, when I find one, I get the returned string, and the start position of that string in the source.

What is the easiest and quickest way for me to then generate an XPath for that element based on its start position in the source?

Comment: There's an incorrect assumption in your question that you can speak of "the xpath" of an element. An element has many XPath's that will reach it. The simplest is something like `(//*)[1387]` - but that style isn't very often used because it's not very stable if the document changes. So you need to explain what kind of XPath you want, and what properties you want it to have.

Comment: Hi, hmm good question, I think any XPATH that gets me to that element is fine, whether its the full xpath, or any abbreviated one. The issue I have, is that the only info I have to find the xpath, is the string position of the element.

From this string position. I'm just looking to build the xpath expression in whatever way is simpliest.

Comment: If by "string position" you mean the position of the element in the lexical HTML, that's hard bordering on impossible, because XPath is concerned with the structure after parsing, which loses lexical information such as the amount of whitespace within tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's why asking for ***the*** XPath for a given part of an XML or HTML document is a mistake.

### Character-based reference

If character-position indexing is truly ideal for your purpose, then treat your document as a string and access substrings via character positioning.  In this framework, there will be a single way to specify subparts of the document — *the* starting and ending character position.

### Markup-based reference

If your purpose is to specify a part of a document based on the names and values of its elements (tags) and attributes, then it makes sense to use XPath:

- Asking for *the* XPath isn't useful — there are *many* XPaths for any given document part.
- A significant advantage of XPath is that it allows specification of a document part that can be invariant across different documents and changes to other parts of the document.

Markup such as XML and HTML associate higher-level structure with document parts beyond character positioning.  XPath leverages that reference framework and allows a higher-level specification of document parts.  Such references can be much more robust across both document instances and document changes.

Do not think in terms of ***the*** XPath but rather in terms of where in the space of element names, element values, attribute names, and attribute values the part of your document of interest resides.  The ability to specify document parts in those terms is the power XPath provides.

Comment: My main goal is to extract CSS attributes from the element that I've found. Unless im mistaken, it seems targetting the most exact xpath for that element is the quickest way for me to retrieve those values

Comment: XPath can only access actual XML or HTML attributes on elements.  If there is a `class` or `style` attribute, XPath can access that.  If you're trying to get CSS properties specified via an internal stylesheet, external stylesheet, or JavaScript settings, XPath is not going to help.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm doing is using Selenium find_element using XPATH, this is then retrieving me the CSS value I need. This will return the "computed" value I want, which I can't neccesarily get from that elements class, because its parents class may be where the attribute is being defined.

Comment: Ok, then it comes down to the particulars of the document and the invariants you can depend upon over time and over other document instances for which the XPath must work.  Can't say much more than that without knowing more about those aspects.  Note also that Selenium has CSS-selector-based referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate my understanding is not great on xpath, I know what I want to do, but trying to word it in a way that other more knowledgeable people will understand has been tricky!

Answer (score 0):

you can try some extensions like selenium ide which give the x-path of html page.you can use the extension that by selecting the line..you can also record and play back the selected html tags.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the use of such an extension could be automated? I want to avoid any interaction with chrome itself.

Comment: @Milinekticker1  i didn't know about that.(Probably You have to use chrome)..for using extension u have to click the line and the extension gives x-path for that.